# Outlook exports to CSV incorrect birthdays

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I have exported my contacts data to CSV from Outlook and dates appeared incorrectly: most often it is shifted by 1 day (it is by 1 day less in CSV).

It is visible correcly in UI.

Is it possible to fix it? Can I be sure it is always 1 day fixed?

Is it possible to export data from calendar with correct dates?

Comment: Check time zones perhaps?

Comment: Timezone on my computer is correct. What else can be checked?

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, this issue will occur when I switch the time zone and export the contact after creating a new contact. Then the birthday date of the exported contact is the date in the current time zone.

So agree with music2myear. It is suggested that you check your time zone and then, try to create a new contact in the current time zone and export it to check if the birthday date of the contact is inconsistent.

Comment: Maybe. But what to do? Is it possible to know, which timezone outlook thinks it was?

Comment: No, so for now, It is suggested that you could try to create a new contact in the current time zone and export it to check if the birthday date of the contact is inconsistent.

If it works normally, it is suggested that you could reset and save the birthday date of the previously created contacts in the current time zone.

Comment: The idea of "exporting" is to avoid manual work. If I need retyping and resetting, I will just type birthdays by hand, regarding this feature non functioning

Comment: Do you mean you can't export contacts on webmail? If so, after my research,it is suggested that you could try to add a several hours to the time displayed in the current time zone, for example, from (utc-10:00) XXX to (UTC + 08:00) XXX, then export the contacts to check whether the birthday date is displayed correctly and try again and again, which could be a bit of a hassle. (Don't forget to adjust the time zone to your current time zone at the end.)

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.